# Why Java modules usage is not visible/explicit in majority of Maven projects? How does a Maven Projects know which modules to depend on?

Tags: java, eclipse, module, java-module

As most of you know, Java Modules (Platform Module System) have been [introduced in Java 9](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html). Although, I personally never had a chance to explicitly use modules since then. And at the same time, every Java-related tutorial I see, doesn't explicitly use it either. What I mean by that, I never saw people actually using `module-info.java` files, as if this feature is totally not used. Although, looks like it is used "under the hood". Some or my own Maven projects have "Module Dependencies" listed under Java Build Path, but some of them don't. All of them are Spring Boot projects. How does it happen? How does Maven knows which module to depend on if I'm not explicitly using `module-info.java` and not saying things like `requires java.sql;`? Thank you.

P.S.: The question arises from an Eclipse IDE issue where suddenly it's not able to resolve java.sql.* imports and most logical solution would say `requires java.sql;`, although it's listed under "Module Dependencies", so it's linked automatically somehow... So I would like to understand what happens under the hood.

P.P.S.: I have tried to search Stack Overflow for possible answer, but did not find it (mostly Maven module related questions/answers).

Comment: As far as I know, Maven does not care about _Java Platform Module System_ (JPMS) modules when it comes to dependency resolution. Maven only cares about what is defined in the POM. Note a Maven module and a JPMS module are not the same thing. Also, the `java.sql` module is part of the standard library and thus in the "modular run-time image". If your own code is modular, then you'll still need to `requires` it, but if your code is **not** modular, then you should not have to do anything extra to use it.

Comment: In JPMS, (module) dependencies are resolved in advance as Maven does. In contrast to e.g. OSGi, it is not possible to add/remove modules at runtime. So there are scenarios where JPMS makes sense (e.g. building a minimal executable application with [`jlink`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jlink.html#GUID-CECAC52B-CFEE-46CB-8166-F17A8E9280E9)) and others where it does not. Apart from that and in general, modularization with encapsulation via JPMS or via e.g. OSGi is a good thing which can help to reduce the maintenance cost of your code base.

Comment: Thanks guys. Good to know about java.sql module being part of the "modular run-time image". Where can I read more about it? Again, I am asking ti understand why sometimes Eclipse gives errors about not being able to resolve that module even if my code is non-modular. I remember fixing that issue by switching from an Eclipse-embedded JDK 17 to a standalone JDK 21, but I have no idea why it was happening, so eager to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What may confuse you is the overloaded term "module". Maven used the term "modules" before the Java Platform Module System (JPMS) was introduced. Maven modules most frequently appear as part of [multi-module projects](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html), allowing you to group multiple compilation units and express dependencies between them in the `<dependencies>` section, without having to install them to your local Maven repository for compilation to succeed.

When you have a non-modular project (no `module-info.java`), all your classes live in the *class path* or [*unnamed module*](https://dev.java/learn/modules/unnamed-module/), and Maven will also put all your dependencies (and their dependencies and so on) listed in the `<dependencies>` section of your `pom.xml` on the class path, regardless of whether you actually use them in your code or not. Classes on the class path can read all other classes, even if they are in unexported packages according to a `module-info.class`.

There is one exception: since Java 17, JDK modules are always treated as if they were on the module path, so you cannot access their internal packages even from the class path, at least not unless you use `--add-exports` or `--add-opens` on the command line. This is a last resort and libraries that rely on JDK internals are encouraged to migrate away from using them.

If you make your project modular by adding a `module-info.class`, Maven will now put your dependencies on the *module path*. JPMS modules cannot depend on the class path, hence **every** dependency you directly access in your code, even if it does not specify a `module-info.class`, nor has an `Automatic-Module-Name`, must be on the module-path and required by your `module-info.java`.

Comment: Thank you. I understand difference between Maven modules and Java modules. But my question is more about how exactly Maven/Eclipse deal with modules of all the dependencies if my app does not have module-info.java files? You touched it a bit here, but it's still unclear... Where can I read more details about all the rules around that? What if I don't use modules, but my dependency does? What is module path? What exactly means "treated as if they were on the module path"? How does Eclipse know which modules to "require" if I don't explicitly specify that? Thanks.